# Store claimed no returns without loyalty program

Tags: consumer-protection, british-columbia

In British Columbia, is it legal to predicate a retail return with the receipt with having made the original purchase tied to a company loyalty program account? This already contradicts the receipt I received but I want to confirm I understand the consumer protection laws before I report to their corporate.

Comment: It might depend on the *reason* why you want to return the goods. If it is "I don't like the colour" or "I don't need it", etc. then a loyalty program might give you benefits above the requirements of the law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Consumer Protection BC](https://www.consumerprotectionbc.ca/about-us/our-authority-governance/), the consumer-protection authority in British Columbia, [says](https://www.consumerprotectionbc.ca/2011/12/whats_your_refund_policy/):

> Retail sales aren’t bound by BC law to provide mandatory returns or refunds.

> refund policies are not regulated by law. It is up to the consumer to find out a store’s policy. We promise it’s not difficult to do this. Just ask the nearest salesperson you see and ask “what is your return policy?”